# Odd Integral converges but don't know why

Tags: calculus

The integral is

$$I=\int_{0.1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{e^x*x} dx$$

Any ideas on how this converges? Been at this for a while and can't make progress.

Answer (score 3):

On this integration range $1/x\le 10$, so the integral is at most $\int_{0.1}^\infty 10e^{-x}dx\le\int_0^\infty 10e^{-x}dx=10$.